# При присваивании int к char почему то дописывается х ('x2', а не 2)

Tags: c++

При присваивании `int` к `char` почему то дописывается `х` (наподобие 'x2', а не 2).

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Дайте нам код посмотреть!

Comment: В hex'ах не выводите часом? :)

Comment: да наверное отладчик ему показывает '\x2', то есть как код 2 в строке задается

Answer (score 5):

Подозреваю, что Вы делаете что-то вида

```
int i = 5;
char c = i;
std::cout << c << std::endl; // или printf("%c\n", c);
```

Это неверно. Если Вы уверены, что в int содержится число от 0 до 9, можно превратить его в ASCII-код с помощью кода:

```
int i = 5;
char c = i + '0';
```

А лучше выводить сразу `i`. Советую дополнить вопрос кодом, иначе не ясно, откуда возникла проблема.

Comment: char c = i + '0';

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, спасибо, опечатка